# net 7.0: adding reference to multitarget project results in NU1702

Tags: .net, .net-7.0, multitargeting, target-framework

I've got a solution with several projects and one of them is multitargetting .NET 7.0 and .NET 4.8. When this project is added a reference to another Blazor WASM project(same solution, through the `<ProjectReference>` element), the compiler ends up generating the NU1702 warning:

```
  Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1860, 5): [NU1702] ProjectReference 'some_project' was resolved using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0'. This project may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

When referencing multitarget libraries through project references, shouldn't we get the correct assembly version? I mean, since the Blazor WASM is targetting .NET 7.0, I expected to the get the .NET 7.0 version without any warnings. It seems like I'm wrong. How can I fix this warning without using the `<MSBuildWarningsAsMessafes>` options?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of .NET is this project targeting (the one that is referencing the multi-targeted one)?

Comment: Hello. Net 7.0 (it's a blazor wasm project)